# Java library to get Nth element from a Collection or Iterable

Tags: java

I have a `Collection` and need to get the Nth element as returned by its `Iterator`.  I know I can iterate while counting through its `Iterator` elements. Is there a third party library (Google Guava or Apache Commons) that does this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Guava's [`Iterators.get`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#get(java.util.Iterator,%20int)) can help

> Advances iterator position + 1 times, returning the element at the positionth position.

Comment: Nice, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Alternately `Iterables.get(Iterable, int)` can be used directly on the `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ignore this, read over part of the question.

---

You can go like so:

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < max; counter++) 
    current = iterator.next();
```

After that, current will be the max-th element of the order induced by the iterator.

Comment: Please read the question and note "I know can iterate while counting through its Iterator elements"

Comment: Sorry, must have read over that. Assuming the collection isn't in an ordered data structure (like an avl or a skip list) looking for a third party library won't really help you, it'll always be linear time search. Building such a data structure would take super-linear time, so unless you're planning on doing that linearly many times (meaning n lookups for the m-th element), that would be more expensive than just doing it the trivial way.

Comment: Yes, of course it's linear search. It helps in that I don't have write new code and can rely on a proven third party library.

Answer (score 0):

An example of using [Iterators.get(Iterator iterator, int position)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#get(java.util.Iterator,%20int)) to get the 3rd element in `myCollection`:

```
com.google.common.collect.Iterators.get(myCollection.iterator(), 3);
```

*Have used the fully qualified name above in case it is needed, e.g. in Eclipse's Display view.*